# How does JQuery do animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

JQuery is written in Javascript.  As someone who knows a little of each, I have to wonder how they wrote some of it.  How do you animate HTML elements in pure Javascript?  Is it just repeatedly updating the CSS property that is to be animated, using standard DOM manipulation, with callbacks to make it asynchronous?  Or is it something more sophisticated?

Comment: You do realize you can just open up any Jquery.js file and see for  yourself right?  Here is the official source code in its entirety: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src

Comment: [Why not have a look yourself?](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js)

Comment: @asawyer yes, but the source doesn't serve a technical explanation. It just shows how it is down, not why it is done that way and how something like that works in theory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

jQuery animations are just updating CSS properties on a recurring timer (which makes it asynchronous).

They also implement a tweening algorithm which keeps track of whether the animation is ahead of schedule or behind schedule and they adjust the step size in the animation at each step to catch up or slow down as needed.  This allows the animation to finish in the time specified regardless of how fast the host computer is.  The downside is that slow or busy computers will show more choppy animations.

They also support easing functions which control the time/shape of the acceleration of the animation.   `Linear` means a constant speed.  `Swing` is a more typical, start slow, accelerate to max speed in the middle and then end slowly.

Because animations are asynchronous, jQuery also implements an animation queue so that you can specify multiple animations that you want to see execute one after the other.  The 2nd animation starts when the first animation finishes and so on.  jQuery also offers a completion function so if you want some of your own code to run when an animation is complete, you can specify a callback function that will get called when the animation completes.  This allows you to carry out some operation when the animation is complete such as start the animation of some other object, hide an object, etc...

FYI, the [jQuery javascript source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) is fully available if you want more details.  The core of the work is in a local function called `doAnimation()`, though much of the work is done in functions called `step` and `update` which can be found with the definition of `jQuery.fx.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

That's it : a plain old setInterval and some DOM manipulation.

Of course, the code is a bit more complex than that.

Look : http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js , near the end of the file. Search for jQuery.fx.prototype .

Answer (score 1):

When inspecting element during a jQuery animation almost always it changes your CSS code, which is assigned to the element through jQuery that is not really assigned from HTML you write. Get a FireBug if you don't have it for firefox and inspect what's going on while the animations execute.

Answer (score 1):

Without having read the code myself, from what I understand it is indeed using standard Javascript methods and properties to update the DOM elements and CSS styles at regular intervals ("ticks"), which it accomplishes using standard `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` methods.