# Best practice for animation using `setInterval/setTimeout` in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, animation

I thought `setInterval`/ `clearInterval` and `setTimeout` / `clearTimeout`  in Javascript looks a bit low level. Is there any popular design pattern or encapsulation (higher level abstraction) to use these methods?

Comment: Well, design patterns help to solve design problems. They are not about how to utilize some functions. So if there is a problem, we can discuss what pattern would work the best.

Comment: @Axalix sorry for the confusion I made, when I say 'design pattern', I mean 'common pattern' or 'best practice'..

Comment: "Best" evaluated by what criteria? "Popular" infers wide use, but that may not be best for you. Perhaps you can look at some [*animation libraries*](https://www.google.com.au/search?&q=javascript+animation+libary) and work out a more focused question.

Comment: This type of question doesn't work on StackOverflow.  Do some research yourself, then when you get stuck post a focused question about a specific animation problem, not an overly broad question like this.

Comment: Some things to look at [How does JQuery do animations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916421/how-does-jquery-do-animations/9916445#9916445) and [Javascript animation tutorial](http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/).

Comment: @hanfeisun Avoid `setInterval`, use `requestAnimationFrame`. Link: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: @TahirAhmed I found `requestAnimationFrame` is not support by Android native browser..

Comment: @hanfeisun, which is why this link contains a polyfill for those browsers that do not support `requestAnimationFrame`. And yes, in that case, it uses `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid setInterval, use requestAnimationFrame.

- [requestAnimationFrame for Smart
  Animating](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/).
- [Using
  requestAnimationFrame](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/).
- [requestAnimationFrame | The secret to silky smooth JavaScript
  animation](http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/).
- [Leaner, Meaner, Faster Animations with
  requestAnimationFrame](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/).
- [Animating with
  requestAnimationFrame](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_with_requestAnimationFrame.htm).

Or look into existing solutions:

- [GreenSock Animation Platform (GSAP)](http://greensock.com/).
- [Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/).
- [TweenJS](http://www.createjs.com/TweenJS).
- [Move.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/).
- [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).
- ... and [many](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+animation+libraries), [many](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+animation+libraries) [more](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+animation+libraries).